# postgis - using field name in ST_POINT

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to run this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    creator.maps 
WHERE 
    ST_DISTANCE( 
        ST_POINT(10,10)::geography, 
        ST_POINT(geolocation)::geography 
    ) 
    < 50000;
```

But it's giving me the error:

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

geolocation is a POINT type

How do I fix this?

Error:

```
ERROR:  function st_point(point) does not exist
```

Comment: please put the complete error message, as it will indicate the function it is trying to use (including the parameter data type, which is of prime importance here)

Answer (score 0):

The type `point` can be converted to a PostGIS `geometry` first, then to a `geography`.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    creator.maps 
WHERE 
    AND ST_DISTANCE( 
          ST_POINT(10,10)::geography, 
          geolocation::geometry::geography 
      ) 
      < 50000;
```

Note that Postgres native [geometric functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-geometry.html) are fairly limited so you may want to consider storing data as `geometry(point)` instead of `point`

Comment: still doesn't work, the error message is that it doesn't take a `point` type. Updated my question.

Comment: I think I can make it work using `earthdistance` extension instead.